# Global symmetry in gravity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, conservation-laws, symmetry

There exists "folk-theorem" about the impossibility to have global symmetries in a consistent theory of quantum gravity. For example, see [Global symmetries in quantum gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4908/global-symmetries-in-quantum-gravity) .

Typical argument sounds like this:

> Quantum gravity may break global symmetries because the global charge can be eaten by virtual black holes or wormholes.

But nonetheless, one can construct conserved quantities in pure gravity:
$$
J^{\mu\nu\rho}=\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\sigma\sqrt{g}
$$
$$
J^{\mu\nu\rho}=\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\sigma R
$$

Or in gravity with matter:
$$
J^{\mu\nu\rho}=\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\sigma\phi
$$
$$
J^{\mu\nu} =\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\rho\sigma}
$$
$$
J^{\mu\nu}=\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\rho\sqrt{g}\partial_\sigma\phi
$$

Such currents trivially conserved, and doesn't act on fields, but acts on monopole-like operators.

Does this current correspond to global symmetry?

Are some applications of such currents?

Comment: If it helps, the conserved current associated to diffeomorphism invariance is the Einstein tensor : https://web.mit.edu/edbert/GR/gr5.pdf (chap. 4.2)